# Extract Conditional Middle name and last name

Tags: pandas

I have a column in a data frame which has a full name as first name, middle name lastname, however for some records no middle name available and want to make sure that it populates the middle name conditionally based on the available pattern but not sure how I can achieve this.

```
import pandas as pd

name_df = pd.read_csv(r"NameData1.txt",delimiter=",")
splitted_name=name_df.name.str.split(' ',expand=True).fillna('No Value')
##splited_name['middle_name']= splited_name.apply(lambda x : x[1] if x[2] != 'No Value' else '' )
name_df['Middle_name']=name_df.apply(lambda splited_name : splited_name[1] if splited_name[2] != 'No Value' else '')
name_df
```

I want to display the middle name only when it's there else the last name should be populated.

Sample records:

```
Id,name
1,TOM M SMITH
2,Gary SMITH 
3,John C Doe
4,Hary Knox
5,Rakesh Vaidya
6,John Doe Doe
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: What is expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for set new column by condition, here are tested `None` values by [`Series.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html):

```
splitted_name=name_df.name.str.split(expand=True)
name_df['First_name'] = splitted_name[0]
name_df['Middle_name']= np.where(splitted_name[2].notna(), splitted_name[1], '')
name_df['Last_name']= np.where(splitted_name[2].notna(), splitted_name[2], splitted_name[1])
print (name_df)
   Id           name First_name Middle_name Last_name
0   1    TOM M SMITH        TOM           M     SMITH
1   2     Gary SMITH       Gary                 SMITH
2   3     John C Doe       John           C       Doe
3   4      Hary Knox       Hary                  Knox
4   5  Rakesh Vaidya     Rakesh                Vaidya
5   6   John Doe Doe       John         Doe       Doe
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me out , however I am curious to know if same can be done using any of pandas functionality,

Comment: Thank you , I was able to get it done using pandas , Earlier I tried this approach but did not realize to add to axis in the code. it worked now 
     .name_df['Middle_name']= splitted_name.apply(lambda x: '' if x[2]=='No' else x[1],axis=1)
name_df

Answer (score 1):

> I want to display middle name only wen its there else last name should be populated.

So you can do the below using [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
df['middle_or_last']=df.name.apply(lambda x:x.split(' ', maxsplit=len(x.split()))).str[1]
print(df)
```

---

```
   Id           name middle_or_last
0   1    TOM M SMITH              M
1   2    Gary SMITH           SMITH
2   3     John C Doe              C
3   4      Hary Knox           Knox
4   5  Rakesh Vaidya         Vaidya
5   6   John Doe Doe            Doe
```